# Why are there special environment variables (e.g. NODE_NAME) in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Consider the following simple Jenkins pipeline:

```
node( label: 'myNodeName' ) {
  println env.NODE_NAME // successfully prints the node name
  env.getEnvironment().each{k,v ->
    println "${k}:${v}" // results do not include NODE_NAME!
  }
}
```

Why does the `env.NODE_NAME` statement work if the NODE_NAME variable does not appear in the results from `env.getEnvironment()`? Is it some sort of special attribute, or am I doing something wrong? If it is special, where can I get a list of these non-environment variables?

I am trying to dump out my environment for logging purposes, and I was quite surprised to discover NODE_NAME was not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that attribute and several others(`WORKSPACE`, `COOKIE_VAR`, `EXECUTOR_NUMBER` and `NODE_LABELS`) are treated specially ([look at this code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-durable-task-step-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/ExecutorStepExecution.java#L638)). The reason for this, and I'm guessing here, is that these are only populated inside `node` steps (unlike all other variables).

Now, that doesn't explain why the variables aren't available in `env.getEnvironment()`. However, after a quick look at [the implementation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java), it is clear why, [the implementation of `getEnvironment()`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java#L66) only looks at the execution and user-set environment, while [`env.getProperty()`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/EnvActionImpl.java#L88) (used when you do property lookup, e.g.: `env.NODE_NAME`) looks at several other environment sets:

```
EnvironmentExpander.getEffectiveEnvironment(getEnvironment(), t.getContextVariable(EnvVars.class), t.getContextVariable(EnvironmentExpander.class))
```

I can't see any reason why the two aren't backed by the same implementation, might be a bug, or an intentional design decision.

Comment: If anything, this got me the list of "special variables" I wanted. Thanks!